# how can i prevent spam in subscriber in php

Tags: javascript

```
  <form action="newsletter" method="POST">
                        <div class="input-group">
                          <input type="email" class="form-control box-style-1" size="50" name="email" placeholder="Your email" required>
                          <input type="hidden" name="code" value="<?php echo $code; ?>" >
                          <div class="input-group-btn">

                            <button type="submit" class="btn subscribe-btn">Subscribe</button>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                     </form>
```

I have tried to send a hidden code (randomly generated) through form but i am not able to prevent the spam.

Comment: use captcha with session follow this https://www.phpjabbers.com/captcha-image-verification-php19.html

Comment: use double hidden input, the first to define the anti-spam method and the second to pass the verification value

Comment: Random code has to be a part of JS, otherwise it'll be simply parsed by bots

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Random code has to be a part of JavaScript, otherwise it'll be simply parsed by bots

Use [reCapcha](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/) for that; or [extra-header](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/websocket-security#authentication-authorization) for each request (that will be a part of JS); or check RELATIVE_URL to validate that submit was done from [your site](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet).